# Call PHP function using AJAX xmlhttprequest

Tags: php, ajax, xmlhttprequest

my problem is I am not sure how to call my php function from JS. I am trying to learn `xmlhttprequest` but something seems to be wrong with my code:

HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Click">
```

JS:

```
window.onload = initForms;

function initForms(){
    document.getElementById("btn").onclick = doSomething;
}

function doSomething(){

    var xmlhttp;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } 
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            // response
        }
    }
    try {
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "test.php", true);
        xmlhttp.send(); 
    } catch (e) {
        alert(e);
    }
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php

echo "Echo!";
```

EDIT: My question is "Echo" doesn't appear, so test.php doesn't seem to be called?! Why not?
EDIT: In the Firefox console i get the following error: "XML Parsing Error: no root element found". Not sure what to make of it (yes, I googled it..)

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Use developer tool in your browser to see if there is a response. You may need to set a header to make server output json instead of HTML

Comment: Are you actually doing anything with the response?  For example, where it currently says `// Response`, you have to actually do something with the response, such as `console.log(xmlhttp.response);`

Comment: I had an innerHTML in the response which worked. So it seems like There is a response, I just don't see anything coming from the .php file. "Echo!" is  not showing.

Comment: snajps: Thank you! I replaced the innerHTML with console.log(xmlhttp.response); and now it works. I'm not sure why but for now I'll just accept it ;) Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

"// Response, you have to actually do something with the response, such as console.log(xmlhttp.response);"

console.log is worthless, especially if you are wanting to do something with the data.

getElementById("idName").innerHTML = xmlhttp.response;

Is more likely what the OP is looking for.